# A bug with layout of question title

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I have recently encountered the following layout problem.
Was thinking it affects only one site (sorry forgot which one), but then seen exactly the same issue at SuperUser.

The problem is: Question title is misaligned.
Also, the "Tell Me More" banner for non-logged-in users is misaligned as well.

The problem occurs in the following browsers, Windows 7/x64; visual appearance is merely equal:

- Firefox 21.0; switching off AdBlock Plus does not affect;
- Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421 (clear, no plugins)
- Chrome 27.0.1453.116 m (clear, no plugins)

[image: Layout in Firefox]
Firefox 21, logged in normally

[image: Layout in IE9]
Internet Explorer 9, **not logged in**

[image: Layout of Title in IE9]
Internet Explorer 9, clicked to close "Tell Me More" banner

[image: Layout Chrome 21]
Chrome 21; not logged in, clicked to close "Tell me more"

[Link to the SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/163843/can-my-laptop-fan-die-if-yes-what-to-do)

Update: The following CSS is in question:

```
#header #hmenus {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 0px 25px 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 725px;
```

}

Removing `float` and `width` makes it working fine.

Comment: You want to ask this question in this site : 

http://meta.superuser.com/

Comment: @RameshRams I have seen the same problem at another site first. So I guess it's not a local SuperUser problem.

Comment: I can reproduce this on both Super User and Server Fault, but not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @animuson I have hopefully found it in the CSS; let me update the question. Probably it can tell you (or any of SE developers) if it's local to the sites.

Comment: @Mat Oh exactly, thanks.